# Mapping в Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Где нужно делать mapping? В "ClassName.hbm.xml" или "Entity classes". Если можно и там и там, то где лучше?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант маппинга через xml файлы уходит в закат. Как правило такой подход используется на старых проектах, поэтому советую использовать Entity classes. Это и более современно и (на мой взгляд) более удобно.